# Unable to upload to App Store Connect for TestFlight

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, watchos

I'm using XCode 15.0.1 to develop a watchOS app. After Product > Archive, I click on Distribute App, but don't see an option for App Store Connect.

[image: No option for App Store Connect]

Also, I notice the Validate App button is grayed out.

[image]

I made sure Skip Install is No for my app.

Any help is appreciated for uploading to TestFlight.

Comment: Which scheme did you archive?

Comment: Any watchOS device (arm64, arm64_32)

Comment: What if you build the iOS scheme?

Comment: I get an 'Invalid Run Destination' message, and if I change BaseSDK to iOS I get different errors

Comment: (sorry to ask..) is this the first time you've used TestFlight, or is this "my iOS apps work great, but my new watchOS project is stuck..." ?